# Which files should provided with node application to prod

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've create nodejs application and I'll need to ship it ,my question is if I need the following:

- Node modules
- test folder

should I Put both in the gitigonre file and if in addition I should do additional actions on the application

Comment: Node modules folder is not neccessary if your production build script before starting the application will run `npm install` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `.gitignore` node_modules and `npm install` it in every environment separately. You do need that folder to run.

You don't need your test folder to run the app though. You might want to test the app in the production environment though, that depends on your needs.